# After installing Windows 7, I can no longer get to Debian 6 (dual boot)

Tags: windows-7, debian, multi-boot, gparted

I had Debian 6 on my machine (Dell Vostro 260) and used GParted to shrink the partition. I then tried installing Windows 7 on that partition. After Windows 7 installed, I could not choose which OS to run. It would just boot into Windows.

I ran GParted again, and saw that Windows created another partition, labeled "System Reserved". That partition had the boot flag set. I tried moving the boot flag to other partitions, including my Debian partition and one with a file system "linux-swap". No option would actually load an OS or anything except for the Windows partition, which is not what I want.

Is it worth it to try to fix this installation, or should I start over. I have all my data backed up, so I can easily install from scratch if I need to. If I do start from scratch, which OS should I install first? And then, how do I set up the partitions to install the other OS?

Let me know if you have any questions. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because Windows overwites any boot loader it finds.

To make it simple, you should just **reinstall your bootloader**.

Boot Debian installation DVD and find any option to repair the system. If Debian has a graphical tool like Suse's YaST, it will detect the bootloader is corrupted. It will then create a new bootloader with Windows option too.

There you will have bootloader again. No need to format.

For the next time, install Windows first...

Comment: Thanks for the info. There was an option to reinstall GRUB on the Debian CD. But it failed to install. So I'm going to reinstall Windows first, then Debian.

Comment: You should try to understand why it failed. If your laptop is running UEFI I suggest Efililo bootloader. Other things don't currently come into my mind